CSRF token for Mayan EDMS REST API using Axios
we installed Mayan EDMS via docker compose to use it for a variety of files in our Remix webapp.
At the moment the problem is that we cant get the authentication token via post request (or, we can't do any requests at all from our webapp).
We are new at web development and just read about CSRF tokens, which might be the problem here.
we are trying it like this :
const data = {
  username: "username",
  password: "password",
};
const headers = {
  accept: "application/json",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  //"X-CSRFToken": csrfToken,
  // Cookie: `csrftoken=${csrfToken}`,
};
const response = await axios.post(
  "http://localhost:8000/api/v4/auth/token/obtain/?format=json",
  data,
  { headers: headers }
);

We always get a 403 response from the API - do we need to provide the CRSF token? if yes - how can we get it?
Thanks in advance!
